# How to use ST_Union if polygons share the same name using PostGIS SQL

Tags: qgis, postgis

Say I have a polygons that overlaps with each other, How do I achieve the same output as `dissolve -> dissolve field(check "name")` using SQL code?

```
layer fields information:
- name # <-- I want to dissolve by `name` field
- area
...
```

origin
[image: original]
desired output
[image: desired output]

Comment: Get familiar with the basic table expressions and their functionality - you are looking for [`GROUP BY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select st_union(array_agg(geometry_field)) as geom_union
from your_layer 
group by "name";
```

Comment: Hey this works geometrically, however the "value" field is dropped, I tried to add "value" in select statement  "select value, st_union(...)", but an error is raised. What is going wrong here.

Comment: @Cookie, Iclude value field into group by section

Comment: However, if you needed an aggregate (say, sum) of the field `value` you should use `select sum(value), st_union(...)`, but do not use it in the group by section.

Comment: Thank you, adding `value` after group by works just fine. And what if have 10 more to do? Does this mean I have to list each item twice after select and groupby? `select a,b,c,d,e,..... from layer group by a,b,c,d,e,.....`

Comment: @Cookie, yes, that's correct. All fields you need to output other then group operations (max(), count, aggregate() etc.) must be included in both the select and group by sections.